# Retrofit2 + Gson IllegalStateException while fetching JSONArray

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I've just recently started using Retrofit + Gson and though I've looked around for an answer to my problem and tried several solutions, nothing seems to be working, instead resulting with:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Firstly, the JSONArray that gets returned looks something like this:

```
[{
    "id": 23545,
    "title": "some title",
    "description": "some description",
    "questions": {
        "text": [{
            "question": "Some question"
        }, {
            "question": "Some other question"
        }],
        "checkbox": [{
            "question": "Some question",
            "options": [{
                "value": "3",
                "correct": "1"
            }, {
                "value": "2",
                "correct": "0"
            }, {
                "value": "1",
                "correct": "0"
            }]
        }]
     }
}]
```

**This is my Retrofit client...**

```
public class ApiClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://somewhere.com/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

    public static ApiInterface getApiInterface() {
        return getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    }

}
```

**This is the interface...**

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    @GET("rest/reviews.json")
    Call<Reviews> getReviews(@Header("Cookie") String cookie);

}
```

**This is the Reviews model:**

```
public class Reviews {

    private ArrayList<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<Review> getReviews() {
        return reviews;
    }

    public void setReviews(ArrayList<Review> reviews) {
       this.reviews = reviews;
    }

}
```

**And the Review model...**

```
public class Review {

    @SerializedName("id") private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("title") private String title;
    @SerializedName("description") private String description;
    @SerializedName("questions") private Questions questions;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    etc...
}
```

**And the fragment code where I make the request...**

```
ArrayList<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();

ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiInterface();

Call<Reviews> call = apiInterface.getReviews(cbi.onGetCookie());

call.enqueue(new Callback<Reviews>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Reviews> call, Response<Reviews> response) {
        if(response.isSuccessful()) {
            reviews = response.body().getReviews();
            // pass on to RecyclerView adapter
        } else {
            // handle fail
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Reviews> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
    }
});
```

**Gradle dependencies in case anyone's interested...**

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

I understand the error message, I'm just trying to figure out how to make Gson expect a JSONArray. I'm sure my mistake is obvious but I'm not seeing or understanding it. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `Call<Reviews>` should be `Call<List<Review>>`. The rest seems fine

Comment: @Blackbelt thanks, actually I've tried that but maybe I've overlooked something. I'll give it another shot.

Comment: @Blackbelt Thanks, your suggestion and Blackbelt's answer worked equally well. I've tried both ways before but my mistake was with the Reviews class, which both of you made me realize was part of the mistake. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code as below and it should work :

```
Call<Review []> call = apiInterface.getAppraisals(cbi.onGetCookie());

call.enqueue(new Callback<Review []>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Review []> call, Response<Review[]> response) {
        if(response.isSuccessful()) {
            reviews = response.body();
            // pass on to RecyclerView adapter
        } else {
            // handle fail
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Review[]> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
    }
});
```

> I have changes Reviews to Review[] because in your response there is no key "reviews" which contains array of Review.

Comment: Thanks Arpit, your solution and Blackbelt's suggestion both work. Part of my mistake was in using the Reviews model, so trying <Reviews[]> and <List<Reviews>> was never successful.... now I get it ;). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In the interface try

```
Call<Review> getReviews(@Header("Cookie") String cookie);
```

and

```
Call<Review> call = apiInterface.getReviews(cbi.onGetCookie());
call.enqueue(new Callback<Review>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<Review> call, Response<Review> response) {
    if(response.isSuccessful()) {
        String id = response.body().getId();
        // pass on to RecyclerView adapter
    } else {
        // handle fail
    }
}
@Override
public void onFailure(Call<Reviews> call, Throwable t) {
    Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
}
```

});